# How to target all attributes within an HTML tag

Tags: html, regex, grep, bbedit

I want to remove all the attributes within all paragraph tags, but my positive lookahead for the ">" seems to be skipping ahead to ">" in the closing paragraph tag instead of the opening one.

Example:

My HTML:

```
<p class="a" style="b">text</p>
```

What I want to catch:

```
 class="a" style="b"
```

My GREP:

```
(?<=<p).+(?!>)
```

What the GREP catches:

```
 class="a" style="b">text</p>
```

Comment: You may  use `(?<=<p).+?(?=>)`

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to include line breaks in the results?

Comment: `(?s)(?<=<p).+?(?=>)` or `(?<=<p)[\s\S]+?(?=>)`